# How to convert shell script into python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, pycharm

I want to convert this shell script file to python.

```
#!/bin/bash

(cd ../frontend; npm run build)

for file in src/main/resources/static/*;
    do
        rm -rf "$file"
    done

for file in ../frontend/dist/*;
    do
        cp --recursive "$file" src/main/resources/static
    done

mvn clean install
```

I am trying to solve problem in this way:

```
import os
os.system("npm run build")
os.chmod('../backend/src/main/resources/static', 0o777)
for file in os.listdir('../backend/src/main/resources/static/*'):
    os.remove(file)
```

But getting an FileNotFoundErrors [WinError 2] that can't find my files. 
Error also shows up when I try to delete files from a non-empty directory. 
The rmdir command does not work too. 
I was trying to do some permission changes.

Comment: Please insert the full traceback that you receive. My guess is that you are running this from the wrong directory (all your paths are relative, so you depend on where your you run the script from)

Comment: You are using relative pathnames. Try using absolute

Comment: Why do youse python etc. in a maven project? For running npm you can use things like frontend-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the listdir only retrives the filename. And it doesn’t understand wildcards.

Then you should try:

```py
import os
os.system("npm run build")
path = "../backend/src/main/resources/static"
os.chmod(path, 0o777)
for file in os.listdir(path):
    os.remove(f"{path}/{file}")
```